# "Context is null or TenantId is null or UserId is null" when attempting to publish an app to catalog with Microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to programmatically publish our MS Teams app to a tenant's app catalog after an admin grants consent (via the admin consent flow documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent)).

To do this, I found the endpoint `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps` in the Graph API [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsapp-publish?view=graph-rest-1.0), which according to the docs has the following signature:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps
Content-type: application/zip
Content-length: 244

[Zip file containing a Teams app package]
```

However, when I POST to the above endpoint, I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Context is null or TenantId is null or UserId is null",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-07-28T20:33:11",
      "request-id": <some UUID>
    }
  }
}
```

For authentication, I am passing in the auth token I receive from `"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"`, where tenant_id is the same tenant I am trying to add the app to.

I suspect that there might be either an issue with the consent being granted or the internal contents of our app's .zip but I can't tell which is the case. I don't see any error conditions documented on the Graph API docs page, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm that you have followed these steps correctly 1. Have you added the required permissions **AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All**. 2. Created the app package (zip file ) correctly by following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-package)

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT I am getting those permissions, and our app package seems to be set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The appCatalog publish endpoint requires an oauth user-specific delegated token, which is different from the token received from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token`.